# Should weighted voting generally improve the accuracy of a KNN classifier?

Tags: java, weka, knn

I am comparing my 1NN base classifier with inverse distance weighted voting on and off across 30 datasets, and the weighted voting options seems to make the classifier perform the same or worse 90% of the time.

My question is, is this normal or have I implemented some part of the classifier incorrectly?

I am using Java and WEKA. I have tested 30 of the datasets [found here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php). I am running 30 tests per dataset and calcualting the average accuracy. The way I am calculating the accuracy is by counting all of the correct predictions and dividing them by the total amount of instances I am classifying.

The following code will classify an instance by testing its overall accuracy on a dataset 30 times and calculating the accuracy.

```
for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

    if(j == 1) { 
        knn.setWeightedVoting(true); 
    }

    double averageAccuracy = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        double correct = 0;
        for(Instance test : newTestData){
            double prediction  = knn.classifyInstance(test);
            if(prediction == test.value(newTestData.numAttributes()-1)) {
                correct++;
            }
        }

        double accuracy = (correct * 100) / newTestData.numInstances();
        averageAccuracy+=accuracy;
    }
}

averageAccuracy = averageAccuracy / 30;
```

This code is supposed to enable weighted voting using the inverse distance of each neighbour (just 1 in this case).  I have a tally represented by an array, where each index represents a class in the dataset. I then increment the k nearest neighbours class by the vote weight

```
for(Instance instance : kNearestNeighbours) {
    if(this.weightedVoting) {

        double distance = ClassifierTools.getDistance(instance, testInstance);
        double voteWeight;

        if(distance == 0){
            voteWeight = 0;
        }
        else{
            voteWeight = 1/(distance);
        }

        classTally[(int)instance.classValue()]+=voteWeight;
    }
    else{
        classTally[(int)instance.classValue()]++;
    }
}
```

I read weighted voting as an improvement to the base 1NN classifier so I would expect to see some relative improvement however only 3 data sets see an improvement and of those 3 only 2 of them see an improvement of more than 0.5%.

Here is a list of my complete results over each dataset

```
Base 1NN accuracy   Weighted 1NN accuracy
86.75               86.75
66.6                71.83
74.07               72.22
81.76               81.76
71.55               71.55
51.98               51.98
92.33               92.98
85.22               85.22
97.33               97.33
75                  67
69.53               69.53
97.36               97.36
95.03               95.03
96.35               95.68
93.87               93.87
58.24               58.24
61.11               63.4
72.97               72.97
93.33               93.33
89.09               86.31
89.65               89.65
70.99               70.99
72.32               72.32
96.66               96.66
95.001              95.001
77.41               77.41
84.35               84.35
71.73               71.73
57.16               37.37
51.54               51.14
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The typical understanding of weighted voting in KNN is different from what you have described. It is related to how much a neighbor matters relative to other nearest neighbors while selecting the decision for a single object. Hence weighted voting makes sense only for k > 1.

The most common decision selection procedure in KNN is to count the neighbors from each decision class and to select the decision with the greatest count. That is equally weighted voting. But there are other voting schemes usually depending on the distances of neighbors to the classified object. In case of such weighted voting for each classified object KNN sums the weights of nearest neighbors from each decision class and selects the decision with the greatest sum.

A separate question it is what is the best value of k. KNN can select the value of k automatically optimizing the classification accuracy on the training set with the leave-one-out method or cross-validation.

Guessing you are using IBk from Weka, the classifier has the `distanceWeighting` parameter with 3 possible values (see [IBk documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/lazy/IBk.html)):

- no weighting
- weight by 1-distance
- weight by 1/distance

IBk optimizes k after setting the `crossValidate` parameter.

My friend and I implemented an alternative KNN classifier for Weka which has another set of 3 voting schemes:

- no weighting
- weight by 1/distance
- weight by 1/distance^2

In our experiments the last voting scheme with the weights inversely proportional to the square of the distance gave usually the best classification accuracy.

If you wish to try our alternative KNN implementation you need to install [Rseslib](http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/Rseslib) in Weka. Rseslib is an official Weka package. You can install it using Weka package manager (menu *Tools -> Package manager* in Weka GUI Chooser). Restart of Weka GUI Chooser is necessary to make the installed classifiers visible in Weka tools.

The class path of our KNN implementation is `weka.classifiers.lazy.RseslibKnn`. The `voting` parameter defines the voting scheme to be used. The value of k is optimized by default, it can be turned off by a parameter.